# Parsing currency exchange data from https://uzmanpara.milliyet.com.tr/doviz-kurlari/

Tags: java, jsoup

I prepare the program and I wrote this code with helping but the first 10 times it works then it gives me NULL values,

```
String url = "https://uzmanpara.milliyet.com.tr/doviz-kurlari/";
//Document doc = Jsoup.parse(url);
Document doc = null;
try {
    doc = Jsoup.connect(url).timeout(6000).get();
} catch (IOException ex) {
    Logger.getLogger(den3.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
}
int i = 0;
String[] currencyStr = new String[11];
String[] buyStr = new String[11];
String[] sellStr = new String[11];
Elements elements = doc.select(".borsaMain > div:nth-child(2) > div:nth-child(1) > table.table-markets");
for (Element element : elements) {
    Elements curreny = element.parent().select("td:nth-child(2)");
    Elements buy = element.parent().select("td:nth-child(3)");
    Elements sell = element.parent().select("td:nth-child(4)");
    System.out.println(i);
    currencyStr[i] = curreny.text();
    buyStr[i] = buy.text();
    sellStr[i] = sell.text();
    System.out.println(String.format("%s [buy=%s, sell=%s]",
            curreny.text(), buy.text(), sell.text()));
    i++;
}

for(i = 0; i < 11; i++){
    System.out.println("currency: " + currencyStr[i]);
    System.out.println("buy: " + buyStr[i]);
    System.out.println("sell: " + sellStr[i]);
}
```

here is the code, I guess it is a connection problem but I could not solve it I use Netbeans, Do I have to change the connection properties of Netbeans or should I have to add something more in the code

can you help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with the connection. Your query simply doesn't match the page structure.

Somewhere on your page, there's an element with class `borsaMain`, that has a direct child with class `detL`. And then *somewhere* in the descendants tree of `detL`, there is your `table`. You can write this as the following CSS element selector query:

```
.borsaMain > .detL table
```

There will be two tables in the result, but I suspect you are looking for the first one.

So basically, you want something like:

```java
Element table = doc.selectFirst(".borsaMain > .detL table");
for (Element row : table.select("tr:has(td)")) {
    // your existing loop code
}
```

Comment: thanks for your considerations, it is now working, I am afraid it then stops working, now there is not any problem, my best regards...